# Couchbase sync gateway:: After make some update in document. I not get immediately update in view

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

If I add the new document in Couchbase Sync Gateway and try to fetch from the view, I do not get that document immediately, but after some time I get that document.

What I miss??

Comment: What versions of Couchbase Server and Sync Gateway are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and fined this [post](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/727).

> Thanks @shirshir for suggesting that. You're right - for Couchbase
>   Server 3.0 and higher, the indexable flag is no longer required on
>   write for a 'read-your-own-write' scenario - you should be able to do
>   a standard write and then a query with stale=false to see that data.
>
> For Couchbase Server versions 2.x I believe you'd still need to force
>   persistence (with Indexable) on the write to ensure you're going to
>   see the results in your stale=false query.

I also use that flag and now it works fine.